# What's the meaning of 'baby-belly pooch'?

Tags: meaning

I saw the word from some writing related to pregnancy. 
It sounds like describing a woman having a slightly bulged belly due to the baby but I am not sure. 
Do it describe fat or just its bulged shape? And why there is baby in front to belly pouch?

Here is the writing I saw.

> But some women have a little ***baby-belly pooch*** by the end of the first trimester.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the belly that  remains visible after pregnancy:

> - Now that your baby has come along. You probably want to get back to the way you looked before. ***But for some reason that post "[baby belly pooch](http://www.firstcandle.org/what-is-that-post-baby-belly-pooch-and-how-do-i-fix-it/)" is more stubborn than you think it should be.*** Cutting back on calories and exercising more doesn't seem to be making a difference. What's going on? Well, it's not fat. It is a muscle condition called Diastasis Recti and it means your belly sticks out because the space between your left and right belly muscles has widened.

(www.firstcandle.org)

Comment: Another common term is "baby weight".

Answer (score 2):

In this instance **Pooch** means bulge out... it is not referring to a "pouch" nor suggesting that their belly is a dog. More commonly you'll see a reference to some pooching their lips for a kiss...